# List every combination of a list's elements

Tags: python

I'm trying to retrieve every combination of a list's elements in a variable but one at a time,
I used this code that I modified to fit my program :

```
import itertools
stuff = [1, 2, 3]
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        print(subset)
```

in my program, the list "stuff" contains the alphabet and numbers,
but the problem is that I retrieve the combinations like "a", "b",..., "y", "z" and then i would like to get "aa", "ab", "ac",... but it doesn't return "aa", as if it skipped it, it comes to "ab" directly.

I'm new to this forum, it's my first question so it might not be perfect
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating permutations with repetitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099987/generating-permutations-with-repetitions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all possible combination of values in a list -- Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535439/get-all-possible-combination-of-values-in-a-list-python)

Comment: You want [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) (or [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) if both "ab" and  "ba")

Comment: Can you give your expected output for `[1,2,3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looking for `combinations` of elements from an existing collection, but for all possible `product`s of the elements of that collection:

```
import itertools

stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for n in range(0, len(stuff) + 1):
    for result in itertools.product(stuff, repeat=n):
        print(result)
```

Output:

```
()
('a',)
('b',)
('c',)
('a', 'a')
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('b', 'a')
('b', 'b')
('b', 'c')
('c', 'a')
('c', 'b')
('c', 'c')
('a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'b')
('a', 'a', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'a')
('a', 'b', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'a')
('a', 'c', 'b')
('a', 'c', 'c')
('b', 'a', 'a')
('b', 'a', 'b')
('b', 'a', 'c')
('b', 'b', 'a')
('b', 'b', 'b')
('b', 'b', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'a')
('b', 'c', 'b')
('b', 'c', 'c')
('c', 'a', 'a')
('c', 'a', 'b')
('c', 'a', 'c')
('c', 'b', 'a')
('c', 'b', 'b')
('c', 'b', 'c')
('c', 'c', 'a')
('c', 'c', 'b')
('c', 'c', 'c')
```

Note: I renamed `L` to `n`, because it's generally not a good idea to name variables and functions in Python with capitals and I renamed `subset` to `result` because what both `combinations` and `product` produce are not `set`s but `tuple`s.

As @mozway correctly points out, you may consider an example like `('a', 'b')` and `('b', 'a')` duplicates, in which case you want `combinations_with_replacement`:

```
import itertools
stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for n in range(0, len(stuff) + 1):
    for result in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(stuff, r=n):
        print(result)
```

Output:

```
()
('a',)
('b',)
('c',)
('a', 'a')
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('b', 'b')
('b', 'c')
('c', 'c')
('a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'b')
('a', 'a', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'c')
('b', 'b', 'b')
('b', 'b', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'c')
('c', 'c', 'c')
```

Comment: Or [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement), the question is unclear.